# Angular Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following in angular 1.3.14:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at eval (native)
    at Function.n.extend.globalEval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:2538)
    at n.fn.extend.domManip (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:17203)
    at n.fn.extend.append (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:14886)
    at null.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:16246)
    at n.access (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:30124)
    at n.fn.extend.html (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:15917)
    at link (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js:7:200)
    at Z (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:70:149)
    at A (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:59:203) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607$get @ angular.js:8557Z @ angular.js:8221A @ angular.js:7729g @ angular.js:7078(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6957$get.h @ angular.js:7096l @ angular.js:7756x @ angular-route.js:933$get.l.$broadcast @ angular.js:14720(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:616(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13189$get.l.$eval @ angular.js:14401$get.l.$digest @ angular.js:14217$get.l.$apply @ angular.js:14506l @ angular.js:9659S @ angular.js:9849D.onload @ angular.js:9790
arguments
[SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at eval (native)
    at Function.n.extend.globalEval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:2538)
    at n.fn.extend.domManip (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:17203)
    at n.fn.extend.append (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:14886)
    at null.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:16246)
    at n.access (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:30124)
    at n.fn.extend.html (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:15917)
    at link (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js:7:200)
    at Z (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:70:149)
    at A (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:59:203), "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"]
```

Source snippet:

```
    function consoleLog(type) {
      var console = $window.console || {},
          logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
          hasApply = false;

      // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
      // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
      try {
        hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
      } catch (e) {}

      if (hasApply) {
        return function() {
          var args = [];
          forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
            args.push(formatError(arg));
          });
          return logFn.apply(console, args);
        };
      }

      // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
      // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
      return function(arg1, arg2) {
        logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
      };
    }
  }];
}
```

```
arguments:
    arguments: Arguments[2]
    0: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at eval (native) at Function.n.extend.globalEval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:2538) at n.fn.extend.domManip (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:17203) at n.fn.extend.append (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:14886) at null. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:16246) at n.access (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:30124) at n.fn.extend.html (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:15917) at link (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js:7:200) at Z (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:70:149) at A (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:59:203)
    message: "Unexpected identifier"
    stack: (...)
    get stack: ()
    set stack: ()
    __proto__: Error
    1: ""
    callee: (...)
    get callee: ThrowTypeError()
    set callee: ThrowTypeError()
    caller: (...)
    get caller: ThrowTypeError()
    set caller: ThrowTypeError()
    length: 2
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ArrayValues()
    __proto__: Object
    this: Object
```

Comment: what line in the code throws this error?

Comment: Why the negative vote?  That's as much context as I could find to post in this question.  It was not very clear what logic in my application is the root cause of this and cannot post sample code that duplicates the issue.   The line that's throwing the error in the posted snippet is:  return logFn.apply(console, args);

Comment: The downvote was there when I read the question, but I would guess it came from the lack of a real question; your post has a statement and a wall of error message.

Comment: When I get back to my desk I will try with the unminified angular to see if the root cause is clearer.

Comment: Was an encoding issue with my data.